# Not getting DFP real advertise

Tags: android, addition, adsense, google-ads-api, google-dfp

I am implementing DFP smart banner add.My test add is loading successfully but I am not getting real add. Can any one guide me where I am wrong.

Here is my code:-

```
PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(PublisherAdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("------xxx---xxxxx").build();
        mPublisherAdView.setAdSizes(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
//        mPublisherAdView.setAdSizes( new AdSize(300, 50));
        mPublisherAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I also check it without this `.addTestDevice(PublisherAdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("------xxx---xxxxx")`

and I am getting Failed to load ad: 3 error

While including this line my add display like screen shot given-[image]

Comment: can you check the banner ads id that you have used is same as you have created.
or 
If you have create id just now it would take time to load the ads.

Comment: Yes, I am using same unit- id which created. Do I need to use package name with unit id?

Comment: No i think package name is not required just wait for few hours and check  that ads might be loading bcoz it takes few hours to load ads.

Comment: Instead of PublisherAdRequest can you use below code and try it.

  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);